# Chrome, search, and iframes

Tags: google-chrome, search, iframe

As far as I can tell, Ctrl+F in Chrome does not search through iframe contents.

Is there any way to work around this, or will I have to take control of searching into my own hands?

Comment: It works for me. Do you have an issue with a specific site?

Comment: Yeah, mine. http://pokebattlers.net/ - it's in limited public beta though and all slots are accounted for, so it won't really help =/

Comment: It looks like Chrome search works but it doesn't scroll to content inside an iframe..